Error :Error: (0 , USe.isError) is not a function, Error while Prisma init in NEXT-js app , postgresql
i was trying to build An E-commerce as using next-js, Prisma, PostgreSQL
i followed this steps:
step 1: npx create-next-app@latest .
step 2: npm i --save-dev ts-node
step 3: npm install prisma --save-dev
step 4: npx prisma init --datasource-provider sqlite  error occurred here:
Error: (0 , import_util10.isError) is not a function,




What version of node you're using? I saw a similar issue with a colleague today and it was due to the version of Node she was running (she was running on Node 23.x.; installing Node 22.x solved the problem for her)

There seems to be an issue with the Node.js version, and there is a discussion about it in Prisma#25560. Some of the suggested solutions are:

Downgrade to Node.js v20.
If using Bun, you can try bunx --bun prisma init (although this did not work for me personally).


switch your nodejs version 23 to 22.

Enter cmd in your command prompt
nvm install 22
